# Liquibase 3.2 not finding dbchangelog-3.2.xsd

Tags: liquibase

Running version 3.2 I am getting an error

[WARN] liquibase - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

When I look for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd it is not there, although http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd is.

I came accross this https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1840, which I interpret to say you dont need access to the internet to get dbchangelog-3.2.xsd. It doesnt seem to help when the internet is available but the .xsd is not there.

I have reverted back to 3.1 but would like to know the root cause of my 3.2 problem.

Comment: The 3.2.xsd has now been uploaded so it should be accessible, but it shouldn't be fetched by liquibase. Are you running behind a proxy or have any other strange network settings?

Comment: No, nothing unusual as far as I can tell. It certainly only worked when I saved a local copy of the .xsd and changed to that as a hard coded link address. At the time I thought that you must be only using the local copy if there was not internet access, not covering the case where the internet was available but the .xsd was not there.

Comment: It should never use the network. Could you test with 3.2.1 and if you are still having troubles open an issue at liquibase.jira.com including your xml header?

Comment: I a behind a network proxy, and having major issues trying to get this to work. Getting the same error as in the question, why is the schema not just included in the jar.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the `liquibase` version to the latest solved my problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by distributing the schema with my application and referring to it locally (relative path). In the example below I have the schema file in the same folder as the changelog.

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

<!-- all the things -->

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase does not looking for xsd in Internet. http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd will be replaced to path to java recources

More detailed info can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350054/liquibase-fails-if-computer-is-not-contected-to-internet/32373158#32373158)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue following what found [here](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3472).

The solution works only for the one using maven-liquibase-plugin.
You have to run liquibase migration with the following option `-Dprefer.internal.xsd=true`:

`mvn -Dprefer.internal.xsd=true liquibase:update`

Answer (score 0):

Check your changlog.xml file headers having xsd document version.
If it doesn't match it will during spring boot:run