# Liquibase fails if computer is not connected to internet

Tags: liquibase

When I am trying to start Liquibase (Karaf is used), I get the following error

> 'Failed to read schema document http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xml, bacause 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not '

If computer is connected to internet, this error is not reproduced.

Comment: The funky thing is that even if connected to internet, that URL doesn't point to an existing ressource.

Comment: I know, that was what I was pointing out.

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled across this myself recently.

You need to change this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
```

and remove the URL to the XSD:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
```

Note the space between `http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog` and `dbchangelog-3.0.xsd`. The first element is the URI for the namespace, the second element points to the actual XSD file. If that doesn't include a URL, the XML parser will try to use a local file.

Then put the actual XSD into the same directory where the changelog XML is located.

You need to download that from a computer *with* internet access of course, e.g. using:

```
wget http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
```

or by simply opening the URL with the browser and then saving the file.

Note that you also need to specify a **`.xsd`** file for the schema location, not a `.xml` (as it is shown in the question).

Comment: so it's a liquibase bug? did someone file a bug report?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, it's not a bug. This is how the schema validation works. The XML file specifies the _location_ of the XSD file. The attribute `schemaLocation` tells the XML where to find the XSD file that it needs to validate the XML. If the location is not a local file, the XML parser has to download the file from that location.

Comment: yes, but the location used in the document is wrong; I don't understand whether the document comes with liquibase or is generated by it, in which case this would seem like a bug in liquibase, or whether the document has been generated by OP, hence my question

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have not seen any liquibase in the Liquibase source that have an invalid reference to the schema location (namely: `.xml` instead of `.xsd`). Why the original (wrong) one works _with_ an internet connection I cannot tell

Comment: Thk for your awswer.

But, liquibase has own xsd file in liquibase/parser/core/xml/.

If we run liquibase, for example, in tomcat, it works correctly http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd" will be replaced to liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd by LiquibaseEntityResolver.java

Comment: @AlbertAshrafzyanov: well apparently it is *not* replaced by `LiquibaseEntityResolver` otherwise using the URL would work even without an internet connection. Only keeping a local filename is the only way I found to make Liquibase work without network access

Answer (score 4):

This problem was fixed. It turns Liquibase-osgi.jar contains own packages and also it contains liquibase.jar. When LiquibaseEntityResolver.java tries to find *.xsd, it finds two files *.xsd with same name. And after that liquibase throws Exception. I deleted duplicate files and everything was working

BTW
Root element of changelog file looks like

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thk for your awswer.

But, liquibase has own xsd file in liquibase/parser/core/xml/.

If we run liquibase, for example, in tomcat, it works correctly
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd" will be replaced to liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd by LiquibaseEntityResolver.java

Answer (score -1):

For those using Maven and the *liquibase-maven-plugin* plugin, be sure to add all liquibase dependencies into the plugin dependencies themselves.

e.g.

```
    <plugin>
      ...
      <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           ...
           <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

I had a similar issue where liquibase commands would not work while disconnected, because the plugin could not resolve the local schema .xsd file.